# Probability in the Primes

Tags: nt.number-theory

Given two randomly chosen positive rational integers, the probability that the two numbers are coprime is $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$. This is also the probability that a positive integer is squarefree. Are there generalizations of these results for Gaussian integers? Or more generally for the ring of integers in an algebraic number field?

Comment: I imagine this has been studied before. The probability ought to be $1/\zeta_K(2)$, where $\zeta_K(s)$ is the Dedekind zeta function of the algebraic number field $K$.

Comment: One should be careful to specify what model for random integers is used, since there is no canonical probability measure on the integers...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are generalizations, see [this mathworld article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RelativelyPrime.html) for some results and references. A detailed exposition for arbitrary number fields is given [in this paper by G. Collins and J. Johnson](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5188175/collinsjohnson.pdf)

Comment: This paper deals with the probability that two <i>ideals</i> of norm at most $X$ are coprime, and one needs a small extra argument to deal with principal ideals instead (equidistribution of ideals in ideal classes).



Comment: I believe the authors comment on the distinction...